# Is it possible to refer to the length of the rows/columns of a 2D array being passed as a parameter without additional parameters?

Tags: java, matrix, parameter-passing, multidimensional-array

Let's say we have a function with the following prototype:

```
public static funWithMatrices(int[][] aux)
```

Now, we could do:

```
int i = aux.length;
```

To get the number of `rows` in `aux`. Similarly, we could then do:

```
int j = aux[i].length;
```

To just get the length of each column. But is there a better way to do this? Of course, the compiler can't possible know that what you're passing is a matrix rather than an arbitrary array with differing row/column lengths, but is it possible to constrain it somehow?

I'd be more interested in something that's already built-in rather than creating my own `matrix` object with the given constraints. Though that'd be easy to do, it's not quite what I'm asking.

Sneak edit: I realize there is also the possibility of redefining the prototype to something like `int[][] aux, n, m`, but that is also not quite what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage object oriented programming nature of Java and create your own Matrix class with `getColumnLength()` and `getRowLength()` methods defined, or even better have a look at [Apache Commons Math libraries](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) and leverage existing Matrix API classes and functions

Answer (score 0):

There is also [la4j](http://la4j.org) library that can be used as following:

```
public static void funWithMatrices(Matrix aux) {
   int rows = aux.rows();
   int columns = aux.columns();

   // do what you want with matrix
   // for example multyply each cell by 2 if it's symmetric matrix

   if (aux.is(Matrices.SYMMETRIC_MATRIX)) {
       Matrix aux2 = aux.transform(Matrices.asMulFunction(2.0));
   }
}

// a caller
funWithMatrices(new Basic2DMatrix(new double[][]{ 
    { 1.0, 2.0 }, 
    { 3.0, 4.0 } 
}));
```